# Socket exception 10048 when trying to start Azure emulator

Tags: c#, azure, emulation, azure-deployment

When i try to start up the windows azure web solution it keeps giving me a socket exception with the code 10048, and then stops deployment to local emulator.

[image]

It seems like there are some problems with conflicting ports?

I have tried:
- rebooting the computer too see if there were any programs that were holding the resource - Reinstalling the Azure SDK and tools.

Here is the output from VS:

```
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Remapping public port 80 to 81 to avoid conflict during emulation.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Remapping public port 3389 to 3390 to avoid conflict during emulation.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Remapping private port 80 to 82 in role 'CloudSearch.Master.Web' to avoid conflict during emulation.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Remapping private port 3389 to 3390 in role 'CloudSearch.Master.Web' to avoid conflict during emulation.
Windows Azure Tools: [Listener127.0.0.1:81] Socket Exception (10048) occured when initializing client listener 
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Azure.DevFabric.IManagement.UpdateTenant(String tenantName, ServiceModelDefinition serviceModel)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.FabricClient.AddServiceDeployment(String tenantName, ServiceModelDefinition serviceModelDefinition, String instanceDescriptionPath, ServiceDeploymentOptions options)
```

Hope any of you have an answer, since i have not been able to find much from googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your .csdef project and make sure there is only one http/https endpoint.  You can do this by right clicking on properties in your cloud project and selecting endpoints.  I have found that having both http (80) and https (443) will throw this error.

Also, it may help to stop the full IIS service if you are using IIS Express (default in recent version of the SDK).